# Dart best practices, shall we provide type annotation in parameters?

Tags: dart

According to Dart best practices, which of them is preferred?

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => SizedBox(),
);

ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext _, int __) => SizedBox(),
);

ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(),
);

ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, __) => SizedBox(),
);
```

At some places, I see all of them (analogy here) being used by Google at different times, so which one is actually recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid type annotation as much as you can, this is the benefit of using `Dart` language, why would you want to use those old syntaxes like Java and other programming language offers? So, you should always try to:

Use:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyWidget(context, index), // use of context and index
);
```

---

Next comes, should you use `_` or `name` in parameters list? See, if you need to use variable then go with `name` else use `_`.

Use:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, __) => SizedBox(), // no use of context and index
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A best practice is one which creates the least confusion for you and the other person who reads your code. So, this small effort pays out later. So, I shall go with the first one.

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => SizedBox(),);
```